# How to verify that app binary is pie enabled

Tags: ios, xcode, pie-chart

Since Apple is cracking down on the non PIE enabled apps submitted, I set my target version to 4.3 and the "Don't Generate Position Independent Executables" setting to be NO, but when I submitted to Apple, they still returned saying "Non-PIE Binary - The executable 'MyApp' is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are configured to create PIE executables."

Anyone have an idea what other settings I need to change?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't know what this was, and then realized I was about to try Googling "apple pie"...

Comment: Is your question how to *build* a PIE executable (what you ask in the question body) or how to *verify* the PIE setting (what is in the question title) ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check if it works good
Go to terminal and place yourself in the root folder (just type cd and press enter)
Then type this line in terminal:
$ otool -hv /path/to/MyApp.app/MyApp
(/path/to/MyApp.app/MyApp should be the path to your app)

To get the path of your app, go to xCode, and in the folder Products, you have your app, right click it and **show in finder**, right click it in finder and **get info**, there you have the route. You just have to add in the end of that rout yourApp.app/yourApp

After run that line in terminal, something like this will appear:

```
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
   MH_MAGIC     ARM         V7  0x00     EXECUTE    39       4548   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL PIE
/Users/AGMacBookOscar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Stache-dryffgnvhpkbsxguxecizmadewxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Wisdom.app/Wisdom (architecture armv7s):
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
   MH_MAGIC     ARM        V7S  0x00     EXECUTE    39       4548   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL PIE
```

If under flags section there is a PIE, then everything is ok
you have the info here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1788/_index.html#/apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013354